# Javascript files working on Chrome when accessed through Node.js server, but not working when opened from folder

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, server

Yesterday I split my single Javascript file into multiple files.  When I tried to export/import the additional files, I was getting an error ("Unexpected token export" and "Unexpected token import").  When I removed the export/import lines, the code worked fine through my basic Node.js server.

I was checking something else just now and opened the file in Chrome from the folder (i.e., not through the server but opening the HTML file directly) and got an error, which I tracked down to a lack of sharing between the multiple JS files.  I added the export/import commands again and got the original error.

What's odd is that the code works on the server in Chrome, works on both the server and from the folder in Firefox, but does not work from the folder in Chrome.

Why might it be that (1) I was prevented from using the export/import commands, and (2) I'm getting a perplexing combination of success and failure by launching the file in these different ways?

Comment: Wild guess -- the code on the server is doing some kind of js concat where it is bringing all the modules together for you?

Answer (score 0):

**Export and Import** are keywords introduced by ECMA2016 Specs.
These are not yet supported by latest node out of box. If it worked then am pretty sure you're using babel to transpile the code on the fly. (check in your package.json)

Also modules are not yet supported in browser either.
Hence a bundling system like webpack or browserify needs to be in place to bundle all your javascript modules into one file to make them work on browser. Also, if you're using import and export in those files instead of CommonJS module style `require('')` , then you need to add babel transpilation as a plugin in your bundling tool as well.

http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-use-es6-in-nodejs/
https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

Note: Babel6 has brought in a lot of changes which may not work in the traditional way .so make sure which babel version you're using.

Comment: So my only real options are to use something like Babel or keep everything in one file?  I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible, but I guess if that's what I have to do then so be it.